# When is it appropriate to include images of something?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the discussion related to [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/9809/2604) to a question I asked raised a point for me: when is it appropriate to include images that might be under copyright? It seems that we commonly include such images when we insert screencaps (or images from manga pages) to illustrate something or give more detail.

Is it reasonable to conclude that this is reasonable behavior as long as we are doing this within some sort of [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) criterion?

Comment: Related: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/404.

Comment: @Vogel612: the question there seems related more to issues related to illegal scanlations/fansubs/etc. than what I'm referring to here.

Comment: @maroon the directive stays the same.. don't do something totally dumb, but else don't overthink it. Also the linked question includes "legal copyrighted material"

Comment: @Vogel612: yeah, upon a reread, that seems appropriate